# A local version of the Sobolev inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

A paper I am going through claims the following Sobolev inequality (working always in $\mathbb{R}^3$): for a fixed $R > 0$,
$$
|f(x)|^2 \leq C\sum_{|\alpha| = 0}^2 R^{-3}\int_{B_R(x)} R^{2|\alpha|}|\partial_x^\alpha f(y)|^2\, dy.
$$
My question is how to prove this? I have tried as follows; however I get the wrong powers of $R$.

I have tried proceeding from the usual Sobolev inequality $H^2 \hookrightarrow L^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and multiplying by a cutoff function $\phi_R$, where $\phi_R(x) = \phi(x/R)$ and $\phi$ is a bump function which is $1$ near $0$ and $0$ outside of $B(0, 1)$. Then $\partial^\alpha \phi_R(x) = R^{-|\alpha|}\partial^\alpha \phi(x/R)$, and since $\phi$ is smooth we have $L^\infty$ bounds on these derivatives and can pull them out of the integral after using the Leibniz rule. Since
$$
\partial^\alpha (f\phi_R) = \sum_{\beta \leq \alpha} C_{\alpha\beta} \partial^{\alpha - \beta} f \partial^\beta \phi_R,
$$
we have $|f\phi_R| \lesssim |f|$, as well as
$$
|\partial_i (f\phi_R)| \lesssim |\partial_i f| + R^{-1}|f|,
$$
and
$$
|\partial_{ij} (f\phi_R)| \lesssim |\partial_{ij}f| + R^{-1}(|\partial_i f| + |\partial_j f|) + R^{-2}|f|.
$$
To check the lemma, then, we can check just at $x = 0$ (otherwise translate); then using that $f(0) = f\phi_R(0)$, we have by the usual Sobolev inequality
$$
|f(0)|^2 \leq C\sum_{|\alpha| \leq 2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |\partial_x^\alpha (f\phi_R)|^2\, dy.
$$
Then one plugs in the bounds above in terms of inverse powers of $R$. However one can see that the powers are "off" from the desired estimate on each term; this is seen easiest on the second derivative. The desired result has a power of $R$ on the second derivative term on the right-hand side; however my approach here has no power of $R$ on the second derivative term.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Use $f_R(x) = f(Rx)$ instead in $B_1$ and a cut-off function $\phi \in C_c^\infty(B_1)$ s.t., $\phi \equiv 1$ in $B_{1/2}$, then rescale.

Comment: @r9m, thanks a lot! Do you have some intuition as to why rescaling in the function $f$ rather than the cut-off $\phi$ leads to different behavior in $R$?

Comment: I just looked at the required inequality .. $R^{|\alpha|}$ seems to have come from derivatives of $f$ and $R^{-3}$ looked like volume scaling in dimension $3$. Usually all Poincare/Sobolev inequlities are proved for $B_1$ and rescaled later for $B_R$ ..